# Invalid domains in DNS don't work on mac/*nix like systems

Tags: domain-name-system, mac, nix

At work we use domains like `abc-01`, which work fine on windows. Whilst developing mobile applications we already saw that this doesn't work on both iOS and android which we fixed for a few specific domains (by setting the dns up that `abc-01.def.local` also works in those) and was assumed to be caused by it being an invalid domain. Now however it's necessary to connect through VPN from a mac and changing all relevant domains is **not** an option at the moment (far too many of them and would require changing the settings of far too many applications), so I was hoping whether somebody knows a trick or setting to get this to work on mac (or even linux in general).

Comment: Please elaborate on your meaning of "domains". Are you referring to your AD domain or are you referring to DNS zones unrelated to AD that you host internally?

Comment: Truth be told, I have no idea at all what AD does and what AD domains are, so I guess the second (that's why I labeled it DNS as well). Either way, I found the solution which I posted as an answer below. Apparantly it has to do with automatically adding the search domains.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more searching I found out the solution. The clue was that on newer windows versions we already were instructed at work to enable "Allow DNS suffix appending to unqualified multi-label name queries" and "Primary DNS suffix devolution", but as it was awhile since I had installed a desktop PC at work I forgot about this + didn't see the link.

Either way, next for mac it's necessary to start `mDNSResponder` with `AlwaysAppendSearchDomains` to get it to work (which made me realize that `abc-03` for example wasn't the real domain name in the first place). To achieve this it's necessary to open `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` and edit the `ProgramArguments` array adding `<string>-AlwaysAppendSearchDomains</string>` and next reloading the plist.

Took awhile to find the solution, but happy that I got it to work. Although I am a programmer I really have quite limited knowledge about networks and anything in this area, so I still have no clue what those windows settings do exactly, but at least the mac flag I can comprehend. [Here](http://www.eigenspace.org/2011/07/fixing-osx-lion-dns-search-domains/) is the source btw where I found the solution.